# Datacontext.SaveChanges() adds unwanted records to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I apologize in advance if I'm not clear about my issue but I'm working on a project I don't really understand yet, so feel free to ask to elaborate on a certain part.

Right now I'm working on a test that was already present in the project but didn't work correctly i.e. the data added to the database didn't get deleted and it still used code from before a rework when I wasn't assigned yet. At this moment the test works properly but after it has run there are records left in the database that shouldn't even have been added.

In the code, which you can find here *http://pastebin.com/YzRqi7dt* , you can see the test method. The records that are added in the TestInitialize are deleted properly but after finishing the test there are still 4 records too much in the database. 2 of them are copies of the *ConexioContacts* in the testmethod. I know it are copies because I noticed at a certain point during debugging that there were 8 contacts added instead of 4. The other 2 contacts that remain in the database look like they come from my *Seed()* method, but the Seed() method doesn't get called or anything.

The adding of these 4 records happens during the

```
List<Synchronizer<BaseContact, ExternalContact, ConexioContact>.ConexioEntitySyncContext> matches     =
            Synchronizer<BaseContact, ExternalContact, ConexioContact>
            .FindMatches(conexioEntities, externalEntities, _unitOfWork);
```

when it enters the `DataContext.SaveChanges()` in the background (discovered while debugging). The method above can be found here: http://pastebin.com/t9iMGB31 .  The DataContext.SaveChanges() gets called in the UnitOfWork.SaveChanges() at the end of the method.

Hope this was clear, if not, please ask.

With kind regards,
Gravinco

EDIT:

The transaction suggested by Wyatt Earp resolves the problem if I run my test but I still don't know how or why the error occurred, if someone could elaborate on this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is to wrap all of the work inside of a transaction and roll it back when you're done.  This should keep any changes from hitting the database.  Also, it might help locate the issue, if  it is possibly coming from a different test or something...

Add a `TransactionScope transaction;` object to your test class and at the beginning of your `TestInit()` method, just do `transaction = new TransactionScope()`.  Then, you can replace everything in your `CleanTest()` method with `transaction.Dispose();`

Comment: Hey Wyatt, thank you for respobnding. The problem isn't caused by another test because I only run the test I have given in my question. I have also found out that the line that starts adding these records to my DataContext is unitOfWork.RepositoryAsync<TC>().Insert(insertConexioEntity); in the foreach loop. Does your suggestion still solve the problem in this case? Or am I understanding you completely wrong?

Comment: I don't see where that line is (in your pastebin link), so I can't tell for sure.  However, as long as the database interaction is all happening within the transaction, then the changes should not be saved to the database.

Comment: The line I mentioned is at the end of the else clause in the second link I gave, line 52.
And I'll try the transaction, see if that works. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Gravinco Ah, sorry, I didn't see the second link.  Yes, since that object is passed in to the method, it should be rolled back along with the rest of the transaction.

Comment: Okay, the transaction worked for the test, tomorrow I'll try to see if the code still works properly if I go into the FindMatches() method when I'm not testing but actually running the project to see if the problem lies with my test or the code itself. Thanks anyway :-)